# GKE managed etcd

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I looked for and couldn't find any answers to basic questions about GKE:
- if it is managed k8s does that mean etcd used for storing resources is also fully managed
- how updates and backup on etcd is assured
- what are the limits? What if I have 50000 different resources, most coming from my CRDs

Do you know any official resources that I can refer to and be sure this is really this way?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, etcd is managed and all that it comes with it. There aren't very specific limits defined in the official [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/quotas) although `300,000 containers` should give you a pretty rough idea.

If you have any specific needs, for example, hundreds of Deployments, or ConfigMaps, I would contact GCP support with your specific case.

✌️